# how do i encrypt the password in react-native using base64 encryption ,i am new to react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, base64

This is my code for the file named `LoginBg` in which I have to encrypt the password. How can I get the text from the input field of password and encrypt that using base64 encoding?

```
        export default class LoginBg extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            username:"",
            password:"",
        }

      }

      _handlePress() {
        console.log(this.state.username);
        console.log(this.state.password);
     }


    render(){

    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="position" style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.heading}>- Login Page -</Text>
            <TextInput keyboardType='email-address' underlineColorAndroid='transparent'  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({username:text})} placeholder="Email"  placeholderTextColor="#eaf4fc" style={styles.input}/>
            <TextInput secureTextEntry underlineColorAndroid='transparent' onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password:text})} placeholder="Password" placeholderTextColor="#eaf4fc" style={styles.input}/>
            <Button onPress={() => this._handlePress()}>Login</Button>
            <Button>Register</Button>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
    }
   }
```

Comment: It is important to understand that `base64` is not encryption, so it won't provide any level of security for things like passwords whatsoever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a third-party [base64](https://github.com/dankogai/js-base64) module in this case

**Installation**

> $ npm install --save js-base64

**Usage**

```
import { Base64 } from 'js-base64';

Base64.encode('dankogai');  // ZGFua29nYWk=
```

Comment: Why do you use a external library? Browsers support atob and btoa methods quite good.

Comment: He's building a mobile app.

Comment: how can i exactly use your given code according to mine?

Answer (score 16):

You should not do this, Base64 is an encoding, it is not encryption! You will not have added any meaningful security this way. Passwords are encrypted server-side (if at all, see side-note below), not in the client. Even if you would actually have encrypted the password client-side and sent that then essentially the encrypted password becomes the new plain-text password. If any of this is not clear to you, do some more research before implementing security.

Side note: Even the use for encrypting passwords server-side is limited, generally only if you need it to interact with other systems so you encrypt it before storing it and decrypt before using it. It doesn’t add a lot of security if the decryption key is also stored in the same environment. For your own users that log into your system, the passwords should be *hashed* instead which is a 1-way function unlike encryption.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> yarn add js-base64
> ```

```
import { Base64 } from 'js-base64';

const encode = Base64.encode('hello');
console.log(encode); // encoded value
const decode = Base64.decode(encode);
console.log(decode); // hello
```

If you are using a database like firebase, I would recommend saving your data in a variable like this:

```
const encode = function (day) {
    return Base64.encode(day);
};



const sendMessage = () => {
        addDoc(collection(db, 'matches', matchDetails.id, 'messages'), {
            timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
            userId: user.uid,
            displayName: user.displayName,
            photoURL: matchDetails.users[user.uid].photoURL,
            messageEncrypted: encode(input),
        });

        setInput('');
    };
```

To decode it simply use a helper function like this:

```
const decode = function (week) {
        return Base64.decode(week);
    };
```

Then decode your data by calling the helper function like so:

```
<Text style={tw('text-white')}>{decode(message.messageEncrypted)}</Text>
```